# Can adjectives sound imperative without "be"?

Tags: adjectives

> (be) content with your life!
>
> (be) quiet!

Can't those sentences sound imperative without "be"?
I think they can, but am not sure.

Comment: What do you mean "sound imperative"? "Quiet!" is a very common command. "Content with your life!" is not one, and I'm not sure that its intent would be immediately understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as being idiomatic to command "QUIET!", it is arguably a demand *for* quiet rather than for people to *be* quiet - the noun and the verb are identical. It is worth noting that it is also idiomatic to yell "SILENCE!" (noun) to demand that people *be silent* (verb).

It is *not* idiomatic to say "content with your life!" as if it were an order to *be* content. Yet, it *is* idiomatic to say "*settle down!*" as an order to *be settled*.

The only example I can think of where a verb is used as a command is the military order "at ease!" for someone to *be* at ease. This really falls under the category of *terminology* or *jargon* which do not always follow the rules of grammar. Certain phrases have just become idiomatic through use and there may not be a rule to say what is right or wrong. I would say that incomplete sentences used as commands are exceptional rather than the norm.

Comment: I can think of many verbs that would be used as commands, in particular in the context of somebody pointing a gun at someone else. *Walk!* *Sit!* *Hold still!* *Turn around!* *Put your hands over your head!* (But *ease* is actually a noun in *at ease*, although it's understood to be an elliptical form of ***stand*** *at ease*, where it's that verb that's implied.)